# How do I fetch the value of selected value from drop down in PHP?

Tags: php, html

Here's my drop down:

```
 <form name="form" method="POST" style="display:inline;">
            <select name="category" id="category" value="category" class="form-control ddplaceholder" style="width:220px;font-size:18px;font-family:Roboto;">
                 <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
            <?php
            $sth = $conn->prepare('Select name From category');
            $sth->execute();
            $data = $sth->fetchAll();   
            foreach ($data as $row ){
                if($row['name']!="")
             echo ' <option id=\"CategoryName\" nameCategoryNameVendorName\" value="' .$row['name']. '">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
            }
            ?> 
            </select>
     </form>
```

And I'm trying to access it using the following code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['category']))
     $category=$_POST['category'];
```

When I echo the value of `$category`, it returns null. Why is that? How can I get the value of the selected value from the drop down?

Comment: Select tag is not disabled, just the first value 'Select Category' is disabled for selection. Hey, but let's not worry about it. The drop down is doing its job.

Comment: @Rishi The select is not disabled, is the first option what is disabled. Just right scroll. The action in the form is missing, so by the default it is the same script.

Comment: You have to submit your form.

Comment: What do I submit in that? I wrote it just to display a drop down.

Comment: Is there some dummy value that I can submit?

Comment: We assume you are actually selecting one option, but how do you send the form? I can't see any "send" button

Comment: Oh, I don't think the value is submitting. Can I do it without a button click? How?'

Comment: Quick and dirty ~ `<select name="category" onchange="this.form.submit()" ...`

Comment: Just add a <input type="submit"> tag before the </form> closing tag... reload the page, select one input and hit the button...

Comment: @Phil Doing that puts the default value 'Select Category' on the drop down. Have to retain that even after submit. How?

Comment: With a `selected` attribute on the appropriate `<option>`

Comment: But how will we get the option that was selected before the form was submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi In PHP we can submit form using a submit button or using javascript.
if you want to use only php you shoud add a submit button and check if that is posted then check for category like this.

```
        <form name="form" method="POST" style="display:inline;">
                    <select name="category" id="category" value="category" class="form-control ddplaceholder" style="width:220px;font-size:18px;font-family:Roboto;">
                         <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
                    <?php
                    $sth = $conn->prepare('Select name From category');
                    $sth->execute();
                    $data = $sth->fetchAll();   
                    foreach ($data as $row ){
                        if($row['name']!="")
                     echo ' <option id=\"CategoryName\" nameCategoryNameVendorName\" value="' .$row['name']. '">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
                    }
                    ?> 
                    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
             </form>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
         $category=$_POST['category'];}


or you can try javascript for  submission it will work on change of value in select box

    <form name="form" method="POST" style="display:inline;">
                <select name="category" id="category" value="category" class="form-control ddplaceholder" style="width:220px;font-size:18px;font-family:Roboto;" onchange="document.form.submit();">
                     <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
                <?php
                $sth = $conn->prepare('Select name From category');
                $sth->execute();
                $data = $sth->fetchAll();   
                foreach ($data as $row ){
                    if($row['name']!="")
                 echo ' <option id=\"CategoryName\" nameCategoryNameVendorName\" value="' .$row['name']. '">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
                }
                ?> 
                </select>
         </form>

<?php 

if(!empty($_POST['category']))
     $category=$_POST['category'];
```

Comment: JS code is just document.form.submit()  I have written it in select onchange please have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use input type submit in form to get values in php

```
<form name="form" method="POST" style="display:inline;">
                <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control ddplaceholder" style="width:220px;font-size:18px;font-family:Roboto;">
                     <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
                <?php
                $sth = $conn->prepare('Select name From category');
                $sth->execute();
                $data = $sth->fetchAll();   
                foreach ($data as $row ){
                    if($row['name']!="")
                 echo ' <option id="CategoryName" value="' .$row['name']. '">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
                }
                ?> 
                </select>    <input type="submit" />
         </form>

    <?php
    if(!empty($_POST['category']))
         $category=$_POST['category'];
    print_r($category);
    ?>
```